# Open android app with Volume button

Tags: android

I want to open my application with a volume button?
For example, I have a application, in that there is a button that do a specific task when it is pressed?
I want to do exactly the same via volume button so I don't need to open application.
how do I do this?
Thanks

Comment: You could have a service for your application that has a broadcast receiver setup for boot complete. The service could listen for volume button presses and send a broadcast to a receiver to start up your main activity. I'm not even sure if this would work, and if it does I know it won't be very efficient.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show your work, what you have tried and why it failed, in order to receive help.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, I am a beginner. I have a button which displays hello world when pressed, I want to do this with volume button, here's my method,                            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          });